# MySite My Content deleted

Tags: my-site, user-profile-service, profile-sync, delete, my-content

A SharePoint 2010 My Site application has suddenly deleted all data from the "My Content" area of users' profiles. Does anyone have any experience of this or know what the cause is? There were custom lists etc.

We could restore the database but we'd like to know what caused it so that we can avoid it in future!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a configuration issue with either a AD sync or your User Profile Manager.

There is a timer job that runs and tries to link each mysite with a owner, if it doesn't find it, it starts the clean up. This is basically the thing that will delete the "My Content". Other data will remain in the sync process.

Read up here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362%28v=office.14%29.aspx

You may need to change the timer job times to be away from your AD sync as they may be conflicting and/or they aren't being resolved properly in AD / with the UPM.

You should look for things to do with this timer job in the ULS to see what is going on.

This won't be a straight forward fix, but potentially playing with the timer jobs timing could present a temporary fix, or even disabling it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Hugh. We're yet to find the root cause as we have quite a wide timeframe of around 24 hours from when the data was last seen until it was reported.

Comment: Check the run time of the "My Site cleanup" Timer job. Look at it's last run time under monitoring and then use that as the time to check your ULS logs. A pound to a pinch of snuff that's when they went and your ULS logs will reflect this.